# How can i separate values from the full string, incoming string always changes its positions?

Tags: esp32, string

```json
String str = {"timestamp": "2023-02-08 16-37-31" ,"cpcb_device": [{"Station" : "832","Para": [{"tag_name": "COD","tag_value": "35.5","tag_unit": "mg/l"},{"tag_name": "BOD","tag_value": "13.7","tag_unit": "mg/l"},{"tag_name": "TSS","tag_value": "24.8","tag_unit": "mg/l"},{"tag_name": "pH","tag_value": "6.5","tag_unit": "pH"}]}]}
```

Comment: it looks like JSON format. try the ArduinoJson library

Comment: Using json, it shows derealization error., because string is changed every time from its position

Comment: what is " changed every time from its position"?

Comment: Input string is changed as POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.197
User-Agent: libcurl-agent/1.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 144
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"timestamp": "2023-02-08 16-37-33" ,"cpcb_device": [{"Station" : "833","Para": [{"tag_name": "Flow","tag_value": "2.0","tag_unit": "m3/hr"}]}]}

Comment: use the HTTPClient library for the POST request

Comment: Please some one tell me, how to deserialize this json data, i want only values, so how to separate values from this incoming string

Comment: the HTTPClient library will do it

Comment: `String str = {"timestamp": "2023-02-08 16-37-31" };` returns **error: expected ',' or ';' before ':' token** please fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring() and indexOf() to get parts of the string at certain positions. for example:

```
String test = "timestamp: 123 value: test";

int val = test.indexOf("timestamp:"); //gives you the index for the beginning of "timestamp:"
int start = test.indexOf(" ", val)+1; //get index of the space starting at our 'val' index
int end = test.indexOf(" ", start); //get index of the next space, we added 1 to the previous value so it doesn't pick up the first space
timestamp = test.substring(start, end); //get the characters between these two index values
```

Try it out and see how it works for you, obviously getting the index of separating characters that make more sense, such as a comma or colon rather than a space.
Also you could do it like this:

```
String search = "timestamp:";
int start = test.indexOf(search)+search.length();
//etc...
```